# Vertical alignment with horizontal widths dependent on eachother

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, tablecell

Seems like a simple, straightforward example that's kind of giving me fits. Here's an image of what I'm shooting for:

[image]

HEre's my HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="caption">
        <div class="label">
            Products that matter
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Mauris leo diam, convallis at rhoncus at, pellentesque ut turpis. Nullam orci velit, dignissim a suscipit et, adipiscing vel magna. Mauris leo diam.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.caption {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 66px;
}
.caption .label {
    display: table-cell;
    background: #94749c;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-weight: 400;
    width: auto;
    height: 66px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.caption .content {
    display: table-cell;
    width: auto;
    height: 66px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I think the best way of accomplishing this in pure CSS is with display: table and display table-cell. That way we can get appropriate vertical alignment. The problem is the widths. What I ultimately want is the purple cell to fit to the length of the text whereas the minor cell line breaks.

[Here's a JSFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/W4yse/)

The issue is that, depending on the length of the minor cell, it will push the primary cell in and cause a line break. Also, if you shorten the length of the second cell, the primary cell becomes much too large.

What I'd like to do, without javascript, is have the primary cell auto format its width without line breaking and then have the secondary cell fill in the space and line break as necessary.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems that white-space: nowrap is the key.

That was easy.